# Concentration for Conditional Random Variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, probability-inequalities, inequality

Consider a conditional random variable

\begin{equation}
  X = 
   \begin{cases} 
      Y & \quad\quad ,X \in A \\
      Z & \quad\quad ,X \in A^\complement
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

$Y$ and $Z$ are bounded random variables, both strictly positive, continuous and $A$ is some event. I am interested in the upper bound for $\mathbb{P}(|X - \mathbb{E}[X]| > \epsilon)$. So I start as follows

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
     \mathbb{P}(|X - \mathbb{E}[X]| > \epsilon) &= \mathbb{P}(|Y\boldsymbol{1}_A - \mathbb{E}[Y\boldsymbol{1}_A] + Z\boldsymbol{1}_{A^\complement} - \mathbb{E}[Z\boldsymbol{1}_{A^\complement}]| > \epsilon) \\
&\leq \mathbb{P}(|Y\boldsymbol{1}_A - \mathbb{E}[Y\boldsymbol{1}_A]| + |Z\boldsymbol{1}_{A^\complement} - \mathbb{E}[Z\boldsymbol{1}_{A^\complement}]| > \epsilon) \\
&\leq \mathbb{P}(|Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\boldsymbol{1}_A]| + |Z - \mathbb{E}[Z\boldsymbol{1}_{A^\complement}]| > \epsilon) \\
&\leq \mathbb{P}(\max\left\{|Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\boldsymbol{1}_A]|, |Z - \mathbb{E}[Z\boldsymbol{1}_{A^\complement}]|\right\} > \frac{\epsilon}{2}) \\
&\leq \mathbb{P}(|Y - \mathbb{E}[Y\boldsymbol{1}_A]| > \frac{\epsilon}{2}) +  \mathbb{P}(|Z - \mathbb{E}[Z\boldsymbol{1}_{A^\complement}]| > \frac{\epsilon}{2})
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Now how do I get rid of the conditional expectations. Dropping the indicators will violate the upper bound in the last line. How do I get concentration bounds for the conditional variable $X$. Is there a conditional variant of Hoeffding's inequality that can be used in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could just use Chebyshev's inequality. Since $Y$ and $Z$ are both bounded and positive, then $X$ is bounded and positive. This means the variance should be finite, and Chebyshev's should be applicable.

Comment: Notice, I don't have means for random variables but scaled conditional expectations. To use Chebyshev, I need simple means.